# Program to create LaTeX tables

Tags: latex

I'm looking for a program that helps creating [LaTeX tables](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) by providing many features:

- switching columns or rows
- applying style to cells such as changing the background
- change the style of the bars across the table (thickness, rounding corner, etc.)
- has some attractive templates (for scientific research articles)
- has a GUI

And if possible:

- free
- works on Windows 7

The thread [beautiful table samples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112343/11400) contains some ideas of well-designed tables: I am basically looking for a program that would simplify their creation.

Comment: Is http://truben.no/latex/table/ what you're looking for?

Answer (score 6):

As moose pointed out in the comments, [Table](http://truben.no/latex/table/) is probably the best thing out there.

After hand-filling a table (note you can import and export tables from numerous other cool, handy formats, including csv, Markdown, markup, Mathematica...), lets:

### Invert it

[image]

### Add bars and borders

[image]

You can also sort things alphanumericaly, and other convenient options are avaible.

It is free and works in Windows 7.

### Hey men, that's only half of my requirements

Yep. You may find something that suits all your need, but it seems bad by design to me (and probably to truben.no).

LaTeX is all about semantics, and leaving design annoyances to your stylesheet. Just like I wouldt recommand embedding css glitches in your html code, you should leave the "design" bit in your documents to your stylesheet.

Find a nice stylesheet for scientific research articles that includes one or more cool table-styles, and restrain yourself to these. You may find some "LaTeX-table swiss knife" somewhere, but I truly believe they won't add anything good to your articles.

Note: In the examples you pointed to, I believe many of the tables would have gained in clarity from being split. Huge tables are not cool, really.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/):

- Free and open source
- cross-platform
- WYSIWYG or source edit
- some nice options to edit the tables (see the [LyX documentation](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Tables)) , but it's still pretty rudimentary:

[image]

[image]

[image]